# How to control third-party text-to-speech voices using SAPI 5?

Tags: c#, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

Windows includes the SAPI 5 API that lets you control TTS voices. However I'm using Acapela Peter and it does not show up in the window TTS dialog. So I cannot use this voice with the typical .NET APIs (for example this [codeproject app](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16739/Exploring-the-SpVoice-class-of-MS-SAPI-to-use)). However the voice shipped with this text file : VoiceDescriptions.txt which seems like variables that I can feed into the SAPI engine to help it detect this voice. So my question is : How do I use this voice metadata to generate speech with SAPI? I have all of the referenced files installed with the voice. I found the [SpVoice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723602(v=vs.85).aspx) Win API but it does not mention any way of loading metadata from text.

```
[LANG,British]
@=eng.tml
PHOTREE=eng.trx
PROSO=eng.oso
F0=eng.f0r
DICTIONARY=eng.bab.dca
LDI=eng.bab.ldi
BNF=eng.bnx
BNFNOTAG=eng.notag.bnx
POST=eng.pst
GRI=eng.gri
GRO=eng.gro
SPD=180
Language=British
Info=eng.nfo


[VOICE,Peter22k,British,British]
Base=Peter22k.nuul
Coeff=Peter22k.coef
Database=Peter22k.vco
Info=Peter22k.nfo
Pitch=110
Speed=100
Freq=22050
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Acapela has a [separate product](http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-for-windows-server/product-info/) that adds a SAPI interface layer.

If you want to roll it yourself, you *could* write a [SAPI engine interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717037(v=vs.85).aspx) to the Acapela TTS engine, but that's a significant undertaking (probably 2-3 dev months to create).